# Using input checkboxes with a database--part 2

Tags: php, mysql, input, checkbox

Warning:  This question might be a bit long, my apologies in advance.

So in my last question seen here:
[Using input checkboxes with a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000415/using-input-checkboxes-with-a-database)
I asked the question: "How do I manage multiple users raid attendance with checkboxes and a database loop" and I got a solution that worked in the shortrun, but failed in the longer-run.

Here's the code that runs the loop / allows the user to select who raided:
        
            
              checked />

When I add this to the database, I actually use 3 queries, shown here:

```
foreach($_POST['member'] as $member)
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE attend set rAttend=(rAttend+1) WHERE UserName='$member'");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO attend set rDate =(CURDATE()) WHERE UserName='$member'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE attend set rTotal=(rTotal+1) WHERE UserName='$member'");
}
```

The reason why I can't use a single 'total' is because each user needs to have the total be based off the amount of raids they attended.  Right now the page is displaying like this:

```
http://i.imgur.com/dwxLf.png
```

Despite the fact that I entered a date (with CURDATE()) and had selected the checkbox to be checked.

Here's the full code for the query that displays the above: (warning long)

```
    $query="SELECT rTotal FROM rAttend WHERE Username=('$v_member')";
    $total=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $query="SELECT * FROM rAttend WHERE UserName =('$v_member') order by UserName";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>
<center><h3><?php echo ($v_member)?>'s attendence record</h3></center>
<?php
$i=0;
$j=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$f1=mysql_result($result,$i,"rDate");
$f2=mysql_result($result,$i,"UserName");
$f3=mysql_result($result,$i,"rAttend");
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $f1; ?></td>
<td><?php echo '<a href="'.$f2.'.php">'.$f2.'</a>'; ?></td>
<?php if ($f3 == 1){
echo "<td>yes"; $j++;
}else{ echo "<td>no" ;} ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
$i++;
}
?>
<center>"Raid Attendence: "<?php echo ($j/$total)*100; ?> %</center><br />
</table>
```

If anyone could help me debug this, I would be most grateful, as php / mysql has never been my favorite language.

Thanks a TON!!!

Edit 1:  Shortened posted code by about 30%.

Comment: Horrible code. Format your code properly, and cut it down to what is essential to the question. Thanks two tons.

Comment: @Shef It actually is indented properly, perhaps shy the if/else.  Also, I cut / pasted at some rather odd points since I didn't want to hand out my database details, can you blame me?

Also:  I'm not really too sure what I can exclude from the question...

Comment: Your update loop isn't the same as the one I posted.  The `mysql_query("UPDATE attend set rTotal=(rTotal+1) WHERE UserName='$member'");` should be outside of the foreach loop.

Comment: @Kyle-  The reason that I couldn't use that code specifically is because every user needed to have their own rTotal variable to show how many total raids have occurred since they joined the guild.  If I were to update that outside the foreach wouldn't I just be left with one number for everyone?   Ex:  If someone joined after 5 raids, their first raid would then mean they had attended 1 raid / missed 5?   Am I off base with this assertion?

Comment: @Kyle:  Also, I still am not able to pass whether or not the person was in the raid via the checkbox, since the checkbox already had a value field filled by the membername?  Normally when I use a checkbox I have the value equal to 1, or something along those lines...in this case, I think I'm passing null?  Or I'm just generally mis-handling it?

Comment: @Kyle and just as a final append, my date field just isn't working as expected... despite adding rDate in?   Thanks so much for your help earlier, I'm sorry I was too thick to implement it right on my first try.... C is my language of choice so this is way out of my league.

Comment: The `INSERT` query in the middle is really weird (`INSERT` + `SET` + `WHERE` makes no sense). It's probably failing! And even if it succeeds, it doens't make sense! Then the second `UPDATE` would affect that new entry too.

Comment: @bfavaretto I actually noticed that moments after I posted this and went back to it,  I changed the line to this; which may-well still be wrong:  mysql_query("INSERT INTO rAttend (rDate) value((CURDATE())) WHERE UserName='$member'");

Comment: Still wrong, INSERT ... WHERE makes no sense. What are you trying to do? I think you need an UPDATE to an existing row on your table, not to insert a new row. Right?

Comment: @bfavaretto -  I'm trying to add a date at which a raid took place to each member's raid attendance sheet.  I figure if I could use the "where" here, I could tie a user to all their collective data?   I wish this could just be C++ =(

Comment: Do you have one row per raid per UserName on your rAttend table, or multiple rows?

Comment: I'm thinking of remaking it so that each member will get their own column to make the sorting of data more meaningful, would this make sense?

Comment: Sorry it has taken me so long to get back to you.  If you have some sort of chat program, I will be willing to help you out with this.  I understand what you are trying to do now.

Comment: @Kyle Sure Kyle, if you would like to talk to me, shoot me an email at drivingrain1985@gmail.com with whichever chat program is convenient for you.  Thanks much!

Comment: @Kyle can you check your mail, sorry, I didn't link that right last time.  I screwed some stuff up a few days ago and can't seem to get it right on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working for this on the past few hours, HunderThooves and I finally got the solution.  Haha.

Comment: No joke, just spent like 4 hours with this guy, pretty much have to give him the credit for this answer for one query alone!

Comment: Hey Kyle, can you check your mail, I screwed something up?!

Comment: can you check your mail, sorry, I didn't link that right last time.

Comment: Sorry, have been so busy.  Yes.  Give me about another hour so I can get to a point where I can take a look at it.  In the meantime, would you please email me a little more information about what exactly it is doing wrong?

Comment: I shot you a mail about it a few days ago, it was pretty detailed.

Comment: I responded to your email a few hours ago.  Just posting this comment in case you didn't see it.

Comment: I sent you a reply and an example of the issue.

Comment: Check your email now.  Think I have found something.

Answer (score 2):

On the second line of your display code:

```
$total=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

It seems you're expecting `$total` to be a number, but it's actually a resource (that's what `mysql_query` does, it returns a resource to the resultset). You need something like this:

```
$total_query = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$total_row = mysql_fetch_array($total_query);
$total = $total_row['rTotal'];
```

Comment: That's a really good point too... I honestly didn't even think of that.  This is going to take quite a bit of debugging!